# Can you explain why they have (in bar 7) a fifth interval moving in similar motion in this hymn arrangement?

Tags: theory, harmony

When we study part-writing we often hear about how a two notes making up a fifth should not move in the same direction. I've been told not to do it, but I see professionals hymn arrangements breaking this rule.
In this arrangement of *Abide with me*, you can spot the breaking of the rule in bar 7:

Can you explain why they have (in bar 7) a fifth interval moving in similar motion in this hymn arrangement?

Answer (score 1):

A 5th may not move directly to another 5th.   There's no rule against a 5th moving by similar motion to some other interval.

(That happens several times previous to bar 7 in this piece.)

Comment: Might be so. But I do find that the spunds in bar 7 isn't that smooth, ie too much leaping.

Comment: Smooth isn't everything!  I guess you're talking about the tenor line in bar 7.  Yes, it jumps, and it gets closer to the bass than is generally recommended.   But sing it!  The jump is from ^5 to ^1.  Very strong, and a lovely line to sing!